# Darggable Grid View using pageViewer

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I have developed  Darggable grid view,In this Grid View I have Implemented Darg and Drop Functionality It's Working fine.But As per my requirement I need to integrate this code into

ViewPager.BUt I couldnot drag the icons from one view to another view.I can Drag the icons only one view.Can You PLease solve this if any one knows.

I have implemeted darg&drop functionality using this article:https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Answer (score 0):

DraggableGridView only supports rearranging within one instance. You would need to implement custom events to give your activity information about the currently selected view. You'd have another problem: by default, views don't draw outside of their parent ViewGroup. You might want to try Android's Drag and Drop framework to develop your own custom behavior.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html